# Shell: How to set the working directory for one executing command without affect other commands in a line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two files of code. `./main` needs to be run in the working directory `./../SomeDir/` while `./another` needs to be run in the currect working directory. And I use a pipe as `./main | ./another`. If I can define grammar, I would like to use as:

```
RunWithWorkingDirectory ./main ./../SomeDir/ | ./another
```

So how can I do it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a subshell to limit the directory change to a specific command group, by enclosing the commands in parenthesis:

```
(cd path; ./command)
```

Note that any variable assignment within the subshell will not be reflected in the parent shell.

This can also work with pipes, like:

```
(cd path; ./command) | ( cd path2; ./command2)
```

Comment: In your pipeline, the subshells are not needed since each part of the pipeline is already run in a subshell. It's hence enough to use groupings: `{ cd path; ./command; } | { cd path2; ./command2; }`.

Answer (score 2):

If that's for little parts of your script, user000001's solution is great. If you want it for a more important part, I can think of two solutions:

- The `pushd / popd` combination (only in **bash**). See http://ss64.com/bash/pushd.html and http://ss64.com/bash/popd.html.
- Save the path at the begining of the script (with `pwd`), and `cd` at the end. See http://ss64.com/bash/pwd.html.